# Enable G1GC Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-zookeeper, g1gc

I'm trying to install Kafka in a Jetson Nano (aarch64 architecture) and i'm facing with some problems in installation.

I am following the steps of the Kafka installation tutorial ([Kafka Quickstart Guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)) and when i execute the command

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

it shows me the result below:
[image]

How can I enable this VM option?

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer jdk 1.8.0_281

Comment: that is obviously not the java you start it with...

Comment: G1GC isn't experimental in Java8, but Java 8 is outdated, and latest Kafka (and Zookeeper) supports Java 11. Can you upgrade?